# How to add round edges on top bar of dynamically created stacked bars using Recharts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

At the moment I am creating a stacked bars chart like that:

Compnent:

```
<ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
  <ComposedChart
    data={mappedValues}
    margin={{
      top: 20,
      right: 80,
      bottom: 20,
      left: 20,
    }}
  >
    <CartesianGrid stroke="#EBF0FA" vertical={false} />
    <XAxis
      dataKey="periodFixed"
      axisLine={false}
      tickLine={false}
      tick={<CustomizedAxisTick />}
    />
    <YAxis
      yAxisId="left"
      axisLine={false}
      tickLine={false}
      tickFormatter={formatYAxis}
      stroke="rgba(99, 110, 131, 0.5)"
    />
    <YAxis
      yAxisId="right"
      orientation="right"
      axisLine={false}
      tickLine={false}
      stroke="rgba(99, 110, 131, 0.5)"
    />
    <Tooltip />
    {legendFlag ? (
      <Legend
        wrapperStyle={{
          paddingTop: "25px",
          paddingLeft: "10px",
        }}
      />
    ) : null}

    {groups.map((data, i) => (
      <Bar
        key={i}
        dataKey={data}
        yAxisId="left"
        stackId="a"
        fill={data === groups[0] ? colours[0] : colours[1]}
        barSize={barSize}
        radius={[4, 4, 0, 0]}
      />
    ))}
    <Line
      type="linear"
      yAxisId="right"
      dataKey="transactions"
      stroke="#ADD868"
      dot={false}
      strokeWidth={3}
    />
  </ComposedChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

But the result I get is something like this:

[image]

and I am trying to find a way to add only radius on the top bar of stacked bar chart.
Is there any quick way or a solution for that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this task,

I used `Cell` for the `Stacked Bars` and fixed it like that:

```
{groups.map((data, i) => (
      <Bar
        key={i}
        dataKey={data}
        yAxisId="left"
        stackId="a"
        barSize={barSize}
      >
      {mappedValues.map((entry, index) => (
        <Cell
         key={`cell-${index}`}
         fill={data === groups[0] ? colours[0] : colours[1]}
         radius={renderRadius(entry, data, index)}
        />
      ))}
   </Bar>
))}
```

Where `mappedValues` is my main data object. Then in my function I checked every time if I was on the top bar and if I had value for it:

```
const renderRadius = (entry, data, i) => {
 const length = groups.length - 1;
 if (data !== groups[length]) {
   if (entry[groups[length]] === 0) {
     return [4, 4, 0, 0];
   } else {
     return 0;
   }
 } else  {
   if (entry[groups[length]] !== 0) {
     return [4, 4, 0, 0];
   }
 }
};
```

While the `groups` were coming from the response:

```
const groups = props.data.arrStatsData[0].groups;
```

And that works! If there is any other better solution please let me know :)